# KeyboardDatePicker subtracting 1 day when entering dates manually

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

When I choose date through datepicker, everything is fine. When I put it manually and then save, then to server browser posts other date (here by date I mean date part). My time zone is UTC+03.

Here is my onChange handler:

```
onChange={date =>{console.log(date);setFieldValue('ProjectTimeEnd', date);}}
```

Here are my logs:

[image]

This value were sent to server when I manually set 27 day: (case 1)

[image]

when I set through datepicker: (case 2)

[image]

I can't understand this behavior. If we look at time part (case 1) we can guess we have the same date-time as in console logs, but with different GMT zone. In case 2 our time part is random value.

So my problem is "how to make component in case of manual input use same date regardless GMT zone, same behavior as we have with datepicker"?

Comment: what do you mean by 'manually'?

Comment: @diedu I mean type date directly in input field.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a problem with the picker, can you share more of your code related to the submission and config of your form? are you using formik?

Comment: There is an open issue with material ui's date picker. Follow https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/1526

Answer (score 1):

`KeyboardDatePicker` includes timezone when input by keyboard but not include it when picked by dialog picker, issue [#2024](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/2024). Here is a function to adjust the time to UTC 00.00 for both input:

```js
/**
 * Adjust the the date to UTC 00:00 time regardless input by date picker keyboard or picked by mouse
 * 
 * @param {Date|null} date 
 * @returns Date|null
 */
const getDateIgnoreTimezone = (date) =>
  date && date.getUTCHours() !== 0
    ? ((theDate) =>
        new Date(theDate.getTime() - theDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000))(
        new Date(date)
      )
    : date;

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
  <KeyboardDatePicker
     onChange={(date) => {
       const theDate = getDateIgnoreTimezone(date);
       setFieldValue("date", theDate);
     }}
   />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: This particular example has just resolved two days efforts at getting the date to display correctly. Thank you!